# UIActionsheet orientation issue

Tags: ios4, rotation, orientation, uiactionsheet

I am working on orientation of actionsheet with pickerview. It is working finely on potrait mode but it is not working on landscape mode. May I know where i went wrong?

Regards,
sathish

```
- (IBAction)openActionSheet
{

 UIView *ui_pickerview = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 160, 320, 305)] autorelease];

 pickerViewPopup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@""
              delegate:self
           cancelButtonTitle:nil
         destructiveButtonTitle:nil
           otherButtonTitles:nil];

 UIImageView *pickerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,44,320,213)];
 pickerImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picker.png"];

 UIImageView *homeImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,137,30,24)];
 homeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picker_icon_home.png"];

 m_pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,44,0,0)];
 m_pickerView.delegate = self;
 //m_pickerView.dataSource = self;
 m_pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = NO; 
 //pickerView.


 pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
 pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
 pickerToolbar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:134/255.0 green:187/255.0 blue:34/255.0 alpha:1];
 [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];

 NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(DonePicker:)];
 [barItems addObject:doneBtn];
 [doneBtn release];

 UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
 [barItems addObject:flexSpace];
 [flexSpace release];


 UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(closePicker:)];
 [barItems addObject:cancelBtn];
 [cancelBtn release];

 [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
 [barItems release];



 [pickerViewPopup addSubview:pickerToolbar];
 [pickerViewPopup addSubview:m_pickerView];

 //[pickerViewPopup addSubview:pickerImageView];
 [pickerImageView release];

 //[pickerViewPopup addSubview:homeImageView];
 [homeImageView release];

 [pickerViewPopup showInView:ui_pickerview];
    [pickerViewPopup setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 464)];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not adding your UIActionSheet to a view controller that is handling the orientation for landscape, then the UIActionSheet will come up in portrait.